CORS ASP.NET Core Web API missing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
CORS ASP.NET Core Web API missing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header when I'm trying to get data into my frontend (React + Vite) from backend API. In my backend, I get all responses 200.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace Bakis
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(builder => builder.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
            = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore).AddNewtonsoftJson(builder => builder.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
            // Other service configurations
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            // Allow CORS
            app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}

import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Ticket } from "../types/ticket"
import config from "../types/config";

const TicketList = () => {
    const [tickets, setTickets] = useState<Ticket[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTickets();
    }, []); // Fetch tickets on component mount

    const fetchTickets = async () => {
        try {
            const rsp = await fetch(`${config.baseApiUrl}/tickets`, {mode: 'cors'});
            const ticketsData = await rsp.json();
            setTickets(ticketsData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching tickets:", error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row mb-7">
                <h5 className="themeFontColor text-center">
                    All tickets
                </h5>
            </div>
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        {/* <th>Description</th> */}
                        {/* <th>Category</th> */}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {tickets.map((t) => (
                        <tr key={t.ticketId}>
                            <td>{t.TicketName}</td>
                            {/* <td>{t.Description}</td> */}
                            {/* <td>{t.TicketCategory}</td> */}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TicketList;

enter image description here

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: Same-Origin privacy policy prohibits reading the remote resource from https://localhost:4000/api/tickets (cause: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header missing from CORS request). Status code: 200.

Tried reordering UseCors, chatgpt, reading other stackowerflow posts.
if more code needed just ask me cause im completely lost.

could you try using this code  options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>         {             builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")                    .AllowAnyMethod()                    .AllowAnyHeader();         }); could check what is your header looks like.

Try to use XMLHttpRequest intead of fetch of axios in frontend.
